# what's meaning of it when submit a theme?

Tags: theme-development, wordpress.org, theme-review

**REQUIRED:** Comments are displayed as "Off" while they aren't in wp-admin. Comment form is not displayed in these cases, while it is when a unit test post already has comments.

i have installed the **Test data** . and on some  **post** and **comment test post** pages. these pages had some comments. and  there is also a Comment form  under all the comments. why it notices me,"Comment form is not displayed in these cases, while it is when a unit test post already has comments."

comments are displayed as "Off" while they aren't in wp-admin, what's this meaning? how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. It took a bit of digging and many bad suggestions. The solution is actually quite simple. Just replace this in your theme files:

**Where you have this**:

```
        <div class="comments">
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
        </div>
```

**Replace it with this:**

```
        <div class="comments">
            <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?><br /><p><br /><?php comments_template(); ?><br /></p><br /><?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

**Note:** I thought this was a little ironic, but if you switch your theme to twenty-eleven (the theme that replaces twentyten in 3.2 Beta) it doesn't remove comments like they suggest you should.

You can replace the other code that you are using for the comments_popup_link with the similar condition like this:

```
    <div class="comments">
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?><br /><p><br /><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?><br /></p><br /><?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I'm not sure how the theme review works 100%, but the theme check plug-in says you passed! Here is a screenshot. 
[image: You Passed Screenshot]
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to point you in the right direction, but I'm not 100% sure. I've only been*"Stepping Into Templates"* for a few months (the correct way, not just hacking others themes). I'm sure it is going to be be a conditional statement depending on whether the comments are displayed or not. Since they aren't actually stored on the page, but in their own table of the DB this should be fairly simple. It's a little late tonight/morning, but if this isn't answered by tomorrow I'll try to help you find a solution.

Comment: thanks for your replies. this is my ticket link.http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4198